# How to assign value to azure devops variable using C#

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I have selenium C# test script which can fetch the token from the browser.

I have two azure devops task one to execute the selenium test and another to execute API test.
I want to pass the selenium test fetched token to API test execution task and for that I am trying to use azure user defined variable.

I tried doing `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Token", token);` in my selenium test and then tried to access to token in other API task using `$(Token)`.
But it is not working.

Can anyone please help with this. Is there a way to pass the token from selenium test to other azure-devops task?

Note :- Both tasks are in same job, one after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example: [Set a job-scoped variable from a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#set-a-job-scoped-variable-from-a-script-1).

With C#, that`s maybe like the following:

```
Console.WriteLine("##vso[task.setvariable variable=Token]" + token);
```

Comment: what happens if I already have the same name token(Token) in the realse pipeline variables?

Comment: @PankajDevrani Pipeline will update the variable value for further steps.

Comment: I just wanted to point out for informatio purpose that it does update the variable value for further steps and also it works with secrets as well. Thank you.