# How to assign a variable in Azure DevOps from a .Net Core console app

Tags: c#, .net, azure, devops

I need to create an automation of the environment variable replacement process in PowerApps. The environment variable is the model ID that I trained in Azure Form Recognizer. Now I need to transfer the trained module to another Subscription. For this, I wrote a console application and installed it in the repository. Using Azure DevOps, I launch the application and in the console I get a line with the new ModelID. And now I need to write the new ModelID to the Azure DevOps variable.
I am trying to do it like this - `Console.WriteLine($"##vso[task.setvariable variable=ModelId;]{modelId}");`
But it doesn't work ....

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to try using in this way as  below  [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63034803/how-to-assign-value-to-azure-devops-variable-using-c-sharp):

```
Console.WriteLine ("##vso[task.setvariable variable= ModelID]" + ModelID);
```

Pls check whether you can set the ENV Variable using the below:

`Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ModelID;]<VALUE>"`

If this is working for you, you can invoke the above powershell command using your Console App.